# Shorthand Javascript if statement

Tags: javascript

How would I be able to shorthand the following to one line to keep my code clean?

```
if ($scope.user.unit) {
    $scope.user.unit = $scope.opts.unit[$scope.user.unit.id - 1];
} else {
    $scope.user.unit = $scope.opts.unit[0];
}
```

Comment: What would make a one-liner "cleaner"? Five readable lines is cleaner than one full of ternaries and funky logical operations, IMO. Of course, a single ternary rarely killed anyone.

Comment: I agree with @ssube, readable code is clean code and often more verbose. Its your minifier's (like uglify) job to mangle and compress it into smaller statements for production, not development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary!

```
$scope.user.unit = $scope.user.unit ? $scope.opts.unit[$scope.user.unit.id - 1] : $scope.opts.unit[0];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 $scope.user.unit =
 $scope.opts.unit[$scope.user.unit ? $scope.user.unit.id - 1 : 0];
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the ternary operator `?`:

```
$scope.user.unit = $scope.user.unit ?
    $scope.opts.unit[$scope.user.unit.id - 1] :
    $scope.opts.unit[0];
```

You can also make it more readable (and thus cleaner) by playing around with your variables:

```
var userUnit = $scope.user.unit;
var optsUnit = $scope.opts.unit;

var newUnit = optsUnit[userUnit ? (userUnit.id - 1) : 0];

$scope.user.unit = newUnit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has nothing to be ashamed of as-is, but you could do this:

```
$scope.user.unit = $scope.user.unit ? 
    $scope.opts.unit[$scope.user.unit.id - 1] : 
    $scope.opts.unit[0];
```

Concise code is a good thing, in general, but it's important to get a sense (on a language by language basis) of the fine line between "concise" and "obfuscated".

Answer (score 1):

$scope.user.unit = $scope.opts.unit[$scope.user.unit ? $scope.user.unit.id - 1 : 0 ];

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `||` operator to provide an alternative object when it is missing:

```
$scope.user.unit = $scope.opts.unit[($scope.user.unit || {id:1}).id - 1];
```

Comment: introducing the artificial `{id:1}` does not make the code shorter and **cleaner**

Comment: @xmojmr: That would be your own personal option... What is it that you think is *wrong* with the code, that would grant a downvote?

Comment: OP wanted: shorter equivalent clean code (== faster to read, easy to maintain). What you provide is shorter equivalent code but failing **clean** part of the constraint. You're adding `[($`, `||{`, `}).` ciphers. The new anonymous object disables automatic renaming (refactoring) variable name `user.unit.id`. Introduced new magic constant `1`. Shorter but hard to read and difficult to maintain code, not useful. That is my personal opinion and SO grants me the right to use my votes up/down. Solution of @Anton is better

Comment: @xmojmr: You are using downvotes as an inverted upvote, which means that you automatically upvote any new answer that is added. Do you regularly revisit all questions where you have downvoted to maintain them?

Comment: I don't want your code in my code base. It is a working hack but not useful. I gave you 3 reasons. About my voting behavior - is not voting anonymous and a tool of coming to truth using democracy? What are you talking about?